# Getting the number of Flood events within threshold?

Tags: 8, entities

The `FloodInterface` has 4 methods:

- `register` - which adds an event
- `clear` - which clears an event
- `isAllowed` - which checks to see if the number of logged events is greater than the threshold
- `garbageCollection` - removes expired events

I'm creating an `EntityForm` and need to use the number of flood events to conditionally set certain form elements, does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do that with the default FloodInterface would be to use the isAllowed method and adjust the threshold to the number of allowed attempts.

From a hook_form_alter() you could do something similar to this, where 'my_trigger' is the name of the event that is registered, such as 'contact' for the contact form or 'user.failed_login_ip' and 'user.failed_login_user' for user login. 5 would be the maximum number of times the event could have been registered in 3600 seconds.

```
<?php

function hook_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Hide element if over the number of allowed attempts
  if (!\Drupal::flood()->isAllowed('my_trigger', 5, 3600)) {
    $form['my_element']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```